# Check route if enter this route is permitted or reasonable

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have react app with react router. Route '/item-edit/:itemId' directs user to form where an item can be edited. Deleted items cannot be edited but it is quite obvious. Through application user cannot go to deleted items edit form however he can type proper url (route to form of deleted item) in browser.

How to manage with this situation?

I tried with function (in componentWillMount) which sends request to API to check if item edition is permitted. If it is not, app redirects user to another route (items list). Generally speaking I'm not sure if it is proper solution...

Comment: Try making a top level component that provides a context (a kind of prop accessible to all child components), containing all "permissions" a user has, so you can use this data in child-components to show an edit button or not.
Have react-router render all components that require authentication inside this component, and have this component redirect a user if authentication-data is not provided.

Comment: OK, but still I have to send request to check if authentication-data is provided (in componentDidMount). Am I right?